# How to disable validation on a form in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a very long form with an enormous number of required fields, but I need to run tests by repeatedly submitting the form. It's not feasible for me to fill the entire form with dummy data every time I want to test submitting the form. I've been trying to create a global function that I can call from the console to disable form validation, or just set the form manually to be valid. I've even attempted to loop through every field and set them all manually to be valid, but I haven't gotten anything to work.

How to I override a form to disable its validation or set it to be valid, regardless of the content of the fields?

Comment: You could try to do this: `$valid = true` on the form

Comment: That doesn't work. Tried setting `$valid = true` and `$invalid = false` and an array of other things.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no simple switch to turn off AngularJS validation. Actually most of the validation happens in the `NgModelController` and input directives - basically code in the input.js file. So, to get rid of the built-in validation you would have to re-develop code from this file (plus some others, like select).

Did you identify validation code as a performance bottleneck in your application?

Comment: It's not a performance bottleneck in terms of the performance of the form app itself. It's a development bottleneck in terms of I can't make changes and test form submissions without filling the form out, which means it takes 5 minutes to test a single change in the code because I first have to go through and manually fill the form out with dummy data.

I could create a global function that auto-populates all the fields with valid dummy data, but I thought that would take longer than just overriding the validation. But apparently there seems to be no way in angular to do that.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can add the `novalidate` attribute to your form tag. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp

or

2) I use a pretty helpful extension for Chrome called `Form Filler` wich does exactly what you are asking for, ie: Fills all form inputs in a page with dummy data.